# How can I reassign the semi-maximize keyboard shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys

In Ubuntu 12.04, ctrl+super+(left|right) "semi-maximizes" the window, which docks it to the left or right half of the screen.

How do i reassign this function to use just the super key instead of super+ctrl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install CompizConfigSettingsManager ( `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` )

Go to "Grid" (under "Window Management") > "Bindings" (should be selected already).
From there, adjust the key bindings for 'Put Left' and 'Put Right'.

Comment: great! you saved my life! =)