# Disable "Semi-maximize left" in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, compiz, keyboard-layout

As the title says,

How can I disable or re-assign the "semi-maximize left" keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu 13.10?
By default it is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

I have tried to change the bindings for the "put left" action with `compizconfig-settings-manager` as suggested by the previous question [for Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147105/how-can-i-reassign-the-semi-maximize-keyboard-shortcut). This however no longer works in Ubuntu 13.10.

This question is motivated by the keyboard shortcut [conflicts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412046/unable-to-use-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu) between the default  **Unity** desktop and **IntelliJ IDEA**.

Comment: Refer to the previous question and if that does not give a solution, let me know [Previous question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147105/how-can-i-reassign-the-semi-maximize-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reassign the semi-maximize keyboard shortcut?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147105/how-can-i-reassign-the-semi-maximize-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: @Danatela I have tried changing the "put left" action with `compizconfig-settings-manager` as suggested by [QA for 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147105/how-can-i-reassign-the-semi-maximize-keyboard-shortcut). This however, had [no effect](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1293505). The "semi-maximize left" action is now defined in some other place.

Comment: When you say you tried changeing the binding in CSM, did the setting save ? If so did you try logging out and back in ?

Comment: @NGRhodes: Well, I managed to permanently move "lock screen" to ctrl+super+l with ccsm. This was however only after ccsm broke dash in unity. Luckily I was able to do a Unity reset.

Comment: @Sneetsher: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried `dconf write... left-maximize "'Disabled'"` but no effect. Interesting thing is that I had tab completion available up until `unity/plugins/`

Comment: @EeroAaltonen; Sorry That works for me in 14.04. I have checked a fresh 13.10 install, it seems ccsm changed its place from Ubuntu Unity Plugin to Grid. It seems to me the same thing as "Put left" or "Put right" in Grid. Did I miss any thing, why do they duplicate such options?

Comment: In 13.10, the solution by Sneetsher works. The changes also persist when done through `ccsm`, at least for me.

Comment: A [blog post](http://blog.blzr.me/2013/10/intellij-idea-on-ubuntu-productivity.html) about keymap conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For 13.10

1. Open CompizConfig Setting Manager (`ccsm`)
2. Look for **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** in *Desktop group*  → *General Tab:*
3. Disable:

   - Key to vertically maximize the focused window to the right
   - Key to vertically maximize the focused window to the left

Or just run:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/window-right-maximize "'Disabled'"
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/window-left-maximize "'Disabled'"
```

### For 14.04

1. Open CompizConfig Setting Manager (`ccsm`)
2. Look for Grid in Window Management group  → Binding Tab:
3. Disable:

   - Left maximize
   - Right maximize

Or just run:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/grid/left-maximize "'Disabled'"
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/grid/right-maximize "'Disabled'"
```

Comment: I already accepted your answer, but if you have links to official documentation, they may count to your favor by possible future voters.

Comment: Yep, If I got some I will put them. Just to mention for `dconf` commands, I made change through `ccsm` and monitor changes using `dconf watch /`, Ref: `man dconf`

Comment: For anybody wondering, the 14.04 solution still works in 16.04.