# Were the semi-maximize hotkeys removed? (Xenial)

Tags: unity, 16.04, shortcut-keys

As of yesterday (September 7th 2016) the semi-maximize key combos on my System76 laptop stopped working: The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> commands that would cause a window to fill the left or right side of the screen, respectively.  I've noticed other 'broken' behaviors too: Dragging a window against the top of the screen used to make it fill screen-height, and no longer does so, and the workspace-switching hotkeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+arrows also are not working.

I think these used to be standard Ubuntu/Unity functions; they're listed [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/28087/592472) and used to be in the hotkey overlay but are not there anymore.

I've been hunting all day for bugs or changelogs that would explain these changes, with no luck.  How would I know if this was intentionally removed, and if so, what can I do to get the semi-maximize hotkeys back?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, Unity 7.4.0, compiz 0.9.12.2.  I've also [posted a question on launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+question/388196).

Comment: +1 for posting on Launchpad, good formatting and using <kbd> tags!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is semi-related  to [Ctrl + Super + left/right not working in Ubuntu16.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/821954/295286) from two days ago. Your question is: *Were these shortcuts removed?*  The answer is no , they were not. I'm using Ubuntu with Unity 16.04 and these shortcuts work perfectly fine.

So what exactly is happening ? As I've mentioned in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/822044/295286) to that very same post linked above, your Grid plugin (which was used from [way back in time](https://askubuntu.com/q/435388/295286)) probably got disabled, and you need to check it in the CompizConfig Settings Manager.

There's no exact reason that I know for the plugins to be randomly disabled, but it does happen and sometimes  [too much stuff gets disabled](https://askubuntu.com/q/17381/295286). This is up to developers of Unity and Compiz to figure out,though.

Comment: I installed the CompizConfig settings manager, and sure enough "Grid" was disabled.

Re-enabling it notified me of conflicts - all with window keybindings in "General Options > Key bindings."

After resolving all conflicts and enabling Grid, semi-maximize and window sizing on dragging to screen edge are working again.

I'd still love to know more about exactly what disabled that plugin (which was enabled by default when I got my system a year ago).  It's a little alarming for it to go away, and then need to install a new control panel to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Arrows for workspace-switching hotkeys. Using CompizConfig, make sure that Desktop Wall is enable.

[image]