# How to disable semi-maximize with Super+Left/Super+Right in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

In Ubuntu 17.04 GNOME <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> docks the window to the left or right half of the screen. How to disable this?

Similar: [How can I reassign the semi-maximize keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147105/how-can-i-reassign-the-semi-maximize-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: Left? Arrow, Shift key, Alt or Ctrl key....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to *Settings - Devices - Keyboard* to disable these shortcut keys by clicking on the row and pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Comment: You could've waited another 3 days to make it a full year. I don't know about 17.04 any more, but for 18.04 it's about right.